# One file wants to belong to two users. How? Hard linking fails

Tags: permissions, hard-link

Two setuid programs, `/usr/bin/bar` and `/usr/bin/baz`, share a single configuration file `foo`. The configuration file's mode is `0640`, for it holds sensitive information. The one program runs as `bar:bar` (that is, as user *bar,* group *bar*); the other as `baz:baz`. *Changing users is not an option,* and even changing groups would not be preferable.

I wish to hard link the single configuration file as `/etc/bar/foo` and `/etc/baz/foo`. However, this fails because the file must, as far as I know, belong either to `root:bar` or to `root:baz`.

Potential solution: Create a new group `barbaz` whose members are `bar` and `baz`. Let `foo` belong to `root:barbaz`.

That looks like a pretty heavy-handed solution to me. Is there no neater, simpler way to share the configuration file `foo` between the two programs?

For now, I am maintaining two, identical copies of the file. This works, but is obviously wrong. What would be right?

For information: I have little experience with Unix groups and none with setgid(2).

Comment: The question is generally phased. In my specific case, the two programs happen to be Exim4 and Dovecot, mail-handling programs that can share passwords and TLS certificates.

Comment: the Ubuntu (& I think Debian) solution for this is the `ssl-cert` group, which is pretty much your `barbaz` group. The standard is to set all private keys to be owned by the `ssl-cert` group, and put the UIDs associated with the programs that need to access them into that group.

Comment: @abligh: Interesting. My system is Debian 8 jessie. Apparently, there exists a package `ssl-cert` whose postinst script, at installation, creates the group of which you speak. I had been unaware of `ssl-cert`. Apache2 (installed on my host) *recommends* `ssl-cert`. The various Exim and Dovecot packages do not, but Postfix (not installed on my host) *depends* on `ssl-cert`. Due to Apache, my host does have an *ssl-cert* group, but this group has no members yet. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Make the programs setgid, not setuid. Setuid programs are a bad idea because if they're compromised, the binary can be replaced, creating a trojan horse. (Exception: setuid root, because there you don't have a choice.)

Comment: Does http://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/EximAndDovecotSASL solve your specific situation?

Comment: @MvG: That document, which I had not seen, does not seem to solve my specific situation, but I appreciate the reference. Fortunately, the *accepted* answer does seem to solve it (though even better solutions may be possible, as you note).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use ACLs so the file can be read by people in both groups.

```
chgrp bar file
chmod 640 file
setfacl -m g:baz:r-- file
```

Now both `bar` and `baz` groups can read the file.

For example, here's a file owned by bin:bin with mode 640.

```
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r-----+ 1 bin bin 5 Aug 17 12:19 foo
```

The `+` means there's an ACL set, so let's take a look at it.

```
$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: bin
# group: bin
user::rw-
group::r--
group:sweh:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

We can see the line `group:sweh:r--` : that means people in the group `sweh` can read it.

Hey, that's me!

```
$ id
uid=500(sweh) gid=500(sweh) groups=500(sweh)
```

And yes, I can read the file.

```
$ cat foo
data
```

Answer (score 25):

You may want to reconsider these statements:

> Potential solution: Create a new group barbaz whose members are `bar` and `baz`. Let `foo` belong to `root:barbaz`.
>
> That looks like a pretty heavy-handed solution to me. Is there no neater, simpler way to share the configuration file `foo` between the two programs?

Why is it heavy-handed to create a new group?  Doing so has the following advantages over ACLs:

- Although you have phrased this as a hypothetical with commands `/usr/bin/bar` and `/usr/bin/baz`, it's relevant that these two programs can share a configuration file.  This suggests that the programs are naturally related.  Creating a new group for them would seem to describe a relationship that actually exists and should trigger behavior (such as permissions to read the common configuration file).
- Solving this problem via groups is portable to *every* Unix, meaning that you can rely on the same mechanism, working exactly the same way, on any Unix or Unix-like system.  ACLs are far more complex and portability can be a problem.

Personally I see ACLs as the heavy-handed solution here, and groups as the simpler, traditional Unix way.

Answer (score 16):

I would think this would be a typical use for Access Control Lists (ACLs).  Add both users (or groups) to the config-file's ACL:

```
/etc/foo  root:root rw-------  # Traditional Unix ownership and permission for foo
```

```
$ setfacl -m user:bar:rw- /etc/foo  # Allows user bar to read and write foo
$ setfacl -m user:baz:rw- /etc/foo  # Allows also user baz to read and write foo
```

You may have to install the acl-package first.

Answer (score 3):

Make the file's mode `0660` (or even `0440` if writing is not required) and ownership `bar:baz`. Then one process can access the file thanks to user permissions, the other thanks to group permissions. This works even on file systems where ACLs don't.

Answer (score 2):

> I'll submit this since it's not yet mentioned. Even though this is probably not what you want, it may be the answer for other people with a similar question.

The "new" "cloud" way is to have all configuration handled by a [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) system (such as [chef](https://www.chef.io/), [puppet](https://puppet.com/), or [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)). It does not then matter that you have two distinct but identical files on the server, since both are a copy of the single file from the configuration management system.

The main advantages of doing it like this is that your configuration is [versioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (along with all the rest of your configurations), and that deploying a new identical or almost-identical server becomes so easy that ot can be automated.

(For the record, since you are not using configuration management, I would go with the group system as in @drg's answer).